# Comibine two FilterLists with MUST_PASS_ONE/ALL operator in a single Scan

Tags: java, hbase

Consider hbase shell `scan 'table'` results:

```
ROW COLUMN+CELL
000 column=F:Q, timestamp=1519299345645, value=a
001 column=F:Q, timestamp=1519299345645, value=b
010 column=F:Q, timestamp=1519299345645, value=c
011 column=F:Q, timestamp=1519299345645, value=b
100 column=F:Q, timestamp=1519299345645, value=a
110 column=F:Q, timestamp=1519299345645, value=c
200 column=F:Q, timestamp=1519299345645, value=b
210 column=F:Q, timestamp=1519299345645, value=a
```

What I want as my `scan` result:

- Row key starts with `0` or `1` **and**
- Column `F:Q` value is `a` or `b`

Which for the example above is:

```
ROW COLUMN+CELL
000 column=F:Q, timestamp=1519299345645, value=a
001 column=F:Q, timestamp=1519299345645, value=b
011 column=F:Q, timestamp=1519299345645, value=b
100 column=F:Q, timestamp=1519299345645, value=a
```

In hbase shell, it would be (*ignore all `\s` and `\n` which I put for better readability*):

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.CompareFilter
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SingleColumnValueFilter
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes

scan 'table' { 
  COLUMNS => 'F:Q', 
  FILTER => "
    (
      (PrefixFilter('0')) 
      OR 
      (PrefixFilter('1'))
    ) 
    AND 
    (
      SingleColumnValuFilter(
         Bytes.toBytes("F"),
         Bytes.toBytes("Q"),
         CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'),
         Bytes.toBytes("a")
      )
      OR 
      SingleColumnValuFilter(
         Bytes.toBytes("F"),
         Bytes.toBytes("Q"),
         CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'),
         Bytes.toBytes("b")
      )
    )
  "
}
```

So consider that I have two filter lists in java:

```
List<Filter> prefixFilters            = new ArrayList<>();
List<Filter> singleColumnValueFilters = new ArrayList();

PrefixFilter one  = new PrefixFilter(Bytes.toBytes("1"));
PrefixFilter zero = new PrefixFilter(Bytes.toBytes("0"));

SingleColumnValueFilter a = new SingleColumnValueFilter(
    Bytes.toBytes("F"),
    Bytes.toBytes("Q"),
    CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,
    Bytes.toBytes("a") 
);

SingleColumnValueFilter b = new SingleColumnValueFilter(
    Bytes.toBytes("F"),
    Bytes.toBytes("Q"),
    CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,
    Bytes.toBytes("b") 
);

prefixFilters.add(zero);
prefixFilters.add(one);

singleColumnValueFilters.add(a);
singleColumnValueFilters.add(b);

FilterList prefixFiltersList = new FitlerList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ONE, prefixFilters);
FilterList singleColumnValueFiltersList = new FitlerList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ONE, singleColumnValueFilters);
```

**Question:** How can I combine them for a single [`scan.setFilter()`](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html#setFilter-org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.Filter-) with an `AND` operator, as I did in the shell?

---

I expected to have special [`FilterList`](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/FilterList.html) constructor for that, which would accept logical comparator (`AND` / `OR`) and multiple `List<Filter>` arguments. Since there's none, I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end, add

```
FilterList filters = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
filters.addFilter(prefixFiltersList);
filters.addFilter(singleColumnValueFiltersList);

scan.setFilter(filters);
```

This ensures that both FilterLists are run, and `MUST_PASS_ALL` acts as an `AND` condition.

Why does this work? As per the [FilterList JavaDoc](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/FilterList.html):

> Since you can use Filter Lists as children of Filter Lists, you can create a hierarchy of filters to be evaluated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will check it out at work on Monday and get back to you with kudos!